# Run command in background in Windows from Node.JS

Tags: python, node.js

How can I run a command in the background in Node.JS? In Python I have the following code (for Windows) to make an exe run in background. [`child_process.execFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) didn't have a support for this...

```
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
si.wShowWindow = 4 #constant for SHOWNOACTIVATE

subprocess.Popen(startCommands, startupinfo = si)
```

Is there a support for [`STARTUPINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx) in Node.JS?

Comment: Have you looked at child_process.spawn: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method you want is `spawn`. The thing you want to look out for is how you are running the file. You probably want to execute it using the `python` command rather than running the file as an executable. `spawn` *will* run the file in the background. You may be confused what exactly you mean by "in the background". To clarify *everything* in node can be considered "in the background" if it is not specifically considered a synchronous function. The following will not prevent further execution in node while `runnable.py` is running. However, the `spawnSync` command runs synchronously in node which means it will prevent any other code from being executed while that runs.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn

var runnable = spawn('python', ['./runnable.py']);

//optionally log the output
runnable.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
})

//code here will continue to run while running.py executes
```